# value of hidden input tag changes automatically in php

Tags: php, html

I have a Hidden Input Tag in an edit form with value loaded dynamically from database. My question is when i edit some thing in the form and submit the value of that hidden input tag is as expected, but if I open the form and without touching anything on the form and click on submit button the value stored in that hidden tag changes.

The Button-

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save Proforma Invoice</button>
```

the Hidden input tag-

```
<input type="hidden" name="EditBlocksList" id="EditBlocksList" value="<?php echo $PI["blocks"]; ?>">
```

this is the var_dump of the database value-

```
string(98) "[{"id":"8","blockNo":"PGPL/001","netCUM":"12.92","adCUM":"17.928","rate":"30000","cost":"387600"}]"
```

this is this the values of print_r($_POST); I'm getting on submit-

```
    Array ( [EditCode] => 001 [EditDate] => 16/03/2019 [EditUser] => Jogesh Ravani [EdittMode] => By Road [EditBuyer] => PARADIGAM GRANITE PRIVATE LIMITED [EditsAdd] => SY NO.293/2/3&295/2A/2B/2D/2E/2F, NALLAGANAKOTHAPALLI, HOSUR TALUK, NEAR SHOOLAGIRI, KRISHNAGIRI DIST- 635117 [Editstate] => TAMILNADU [Editgstin] => 33AAFCP5668M1ZW [EditsName] => a [EditsAdd1] => a [EditsState] => a [EditsVillage] => a [EditsPin] => 1 [EditProduct1] => COLOUR GRANITE [EditProduct] => COLOUR GRANITE [Editdescription] => DIMENTIONAL GRANITE ROUGH BLOCK(S) [Edithsn] => 2516 1100 [addBlockNo] => PGPL/001 [newNetCUM] => 12.92 [newadCUM] => 17.928 [newRate] => 30000 [newCost] => 387600 
[EditBlocksList] => [{ 
[EdittotalGrossValue] => 387600 [EdittotaladCUM] => 17.928 [EditrRate] => 3000 [EditrAmt] => 53784 [EditTCUM] => 12.920 [EditTABT] => 441384 [EdittaxType] => INTER-STATE [EdittType] => INTER-STATE [EditpercentIGST] => 12 [EditvalueIGST] => 52966 [EditpercentCGST] => 0 [EditvalueCGST] => 0 [EditpercentSGST] => 0 [EditvalueSGST] => 0 [EditTAAT] => 494350 )
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I only suspect invalid HTML because of quotes (`"`) in the string. Notice how the $_POST shows EditBlocksList only until the first `"`. You can validate your html at [Nu Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). My go-to in firefox is: right-click->View Source->select all->copy. Open the validator, choose "check by: text input", paste the source, click check. This could explain why it works conditionally (invalid HTML often causes unexplained problems); possible solution: `str_replace` change `"` to `'` in the string. When you find the solution, be sure to post is as the answer.

Comment: That string looks like something that would be better off stashed in a session variable instead of a hidden form field.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts to find what may be the problem I gave up and used the following js function as alternative.

```
$(".epiForm").on("click", "button.editPI", function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
     editPI();

});

function editPI(){

     var Blocklist1 = $("#EditBlocksList1").val();
     var Blocklist = $("#EditBlocksList").val();
     var code = $("#EditCode").val();

     var data = new FormData();
     data.append("code", code);


     $.ajax({

         url:"ajax/pi.ajax.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: data,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         dataType:"json",
         success:function(answer){

             var tempBlocklist = answer["blocks"];

             if (Blocklist == "") {
                 $("#EditBlocksList").val(tempBlocklist);
                 $('.epiForm').submit();
             }else{
                 $('.epiForm').submit();
             }

         }

     })

 }
```

And this is working fine for me.